# Sending email to BCC recipients using javax.mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've got the below piece of code, but I can't figure out how to add the BCC recipients to the sendMessage.

Any ideas?

```
           MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

      String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(Calendar
              .getInstance().getTime());

      message.setSubject("This is my email for:" + today);
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("thesender@gmail.com"));
      String []to = new String []{"therecipient1@gmail.com"};
      String []bcc = new String[]{"therecipient2@gmail.com","therecipient3@gmail.com","therecipient4@gmail.com"};
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[0]));
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[0]));
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[1]));
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[2]));
      String body = theBody;
      message.setContent(body,"text/html");
      transport.connect();

        transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
```

Comment: Please, don't edit the queston to become answer. It is confusing as answers and questions are separate on stackoverflow. Just accept the correct answer (maybe also suggesting improvements to it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the following method to add multiple reciepient

```
public void  addRecipients(Message.RecipientType type, Address[] addresses)
```

Also instead of the following line

```
transport.sendMessage(message,message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
```

Try this

```
transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
```

Comment: Seriously? I'm just changing addRecipient to addRecipients on those four lines and hey presto? What do I then do with the message.getRecipients when I do transport.sendMessage?

Comment: Use of `message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(bcc[0]));...` looks correct. Looking at source code there is nothing wrong adding addresses one by one. There is `setRecipient` that would remove previous address, but not `addRecipient`.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String [] to=new String[3];
        to[0]="adfsdf@gmail.com";
        to[1]="dffff@gmail.com";
        to[2]="ddddddddddsssssss@outlook.com";
        InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

        // To get the array of addresses
        for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
            toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
        }

        for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);

        }


        message.setSubject("Testing ");
        message.setText("dddd,"
            + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);
```